# How to reload vim buffer

Tags: search, buffers, plugin-you-complete-me, grep, plugin-easygrep

I built a cpp environment with YCM, EasyGrep and some other plugins.

With YCM, I can jump to declaration/definition, with EasyGrep, I can grep a keyword easily.

But I found something weird:

Saying that I'm coding a c++ project, I put the cursor under `#include <iostream>` and then type `YCMCompleter GoToDefinitionElseDeclaration` to jump to the file `iostream`. After that, I type `<C-o>` to jump back.

Now, if I use `EasyGrep` to grep some keyword, such as `cout`, the searching path will include the file `iostream`. Obviously it is because I just jumped to that file.

As my understanding, vim buffers all of files that are opened by me so that the searching path of `EasyGrep` now includes the file `iostream`.

Is there some way, such as reloading the buffer of vim, to limit the searching path?

Comment: What do you mean... Do you *not* want EasyGrep to search for `cout` in the `iostream` file? Do you want it to search the current buffer only? There's `:bd` that you can use to delete a buffer (have Vim "forget" about a file)... Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: @filbranden or dont use a plugin that searches all buffers :)

Comment: @D.BenKnoble  So do we have another way? In fact I use Nerdtree to load my project, and I want to make sure that `grep` only happens in the zone of my project.

Comment: If you :cd to the root of your project, :grep will only search the current directory (your project). Not sure what nerdtree has to do with it